# Textarea layout problem

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea

I got this small problem but I find it hard to explain so bear with me please.

I got a label in front of a textarea and it looks like this:
[image: screenshot]

And I actually would like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="myform" id="form">
<label>Naam :</label>
<input type="text" id="naam" name="naam" size="40" />
<br />
<label>Email :</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="40" />
<br />
<label>Bericht :</label>
<textarea cols="30" rows="7" id="bericht" name="bericht"></textarea>
<br />
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input class="submit" id="btnZend" name="submit" type="submit" value="Verzend bericht" />
```

The labels in css are: `width:150px; text-align:right;`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
textarea { vertical-align: top; }
```